# how inner products are defined on a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

How do mathematicians define inner product on a vector space.

For example: $a = (x_1,x_2)$ & $ b =(y_1,y_2) $ in $ \mathbb{R}^2.$

Define $\langle a,b\rangle= x_1y_1-x_2y_1-x_1y_2+4x_2y_2$. It's an inner product.

But how does one motivate this inner product? I think there is some sort of matrix multiplication between some vectors.

Comment: I think he's asking what was the motivation for this inner product definition, did it come from some practical purpose the way our "usual" inner product does, but for some other sense?

Comment: @Alan Ya, motivation behind that inner product $<a,b>=x_1y_1−x_2y_1−x_1y_2+4x_2y_2.$ And in general how do they define an inner product.

Answer (score 2):

The abstract definition of an inner product of real-valued vectors is a function $\langle \, , \rangle: \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ satisfying the following axioms, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalars and the $x$'s and $y$'s are vectors.

1. $\langle \alpha x_1 + \beta x_2, y \rangle = \alpha\langle x_1, y \rangle + \beta\langle x_2, y \rangle$
2. $\langle x, \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2 \rangle = \alpha\langle x, y_1 \rangle + \beta\langle x, y_2 \rangle$
3. $\langle x, y \rangle = \langle y, x \rangle$
4. $\langle x, x \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$ if and only if $x$ is the zero vector.

Conditions (1) and (2) tell us that an inner product should be linear in both its arguments.
In addition, condition (2) is not strictly necessary, as conditions (1) and (3) imply it.
This definition also extends to arbitrary vector spaces, not just over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I'm not able to say much about the example of an inner product that you gave however, since I've never seen it before in my life. Could you perhaps tell us the context of the inner product?

Comment: It's from Kenneth Hoffman & Ray Kunze's Linear Algebra. It's an example of an inner product space.

Comment: @RisingStar Ah, in which case, it's probably meant to show that not all inner products need to be like the usual dot product. I would imagine that the authors constructed this purely as an example and would be surprised if it ever shows up in a more natural environment, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Every positive-definite matrix $M$ is associated to an inner product when viewed as a quadratic form. In this case the matrix is $M=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&4\end{pmatrix}$ and the inner product is given by $\langle x,y\rangle=x^TMy$.

Answer (score 0):

Inner product $\langle u,v\rangle$ doesn't depend on the choice of basis. In the given basis $\langle u,v \rangle =x^TMy$.

Every real symmetric matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable: $M=Q^TDQ$, and in the new, "rotated", coordinates $\langle u,v\rangle=x^TMy=x^TQ^TDQy=(Qx)^TD(Qy)=\tilde{x}^TD\tilde{y}$.

The diagonal matrix $D$ consists of the (positive) eigenvalues of the original matrix $M$. By applying a non-uniform scaling transformation one could use the scaled coordinates to write a more familiar $\langle u,v\rangle=\hat{x}^T\hat{y}$.